# Choosing a Java Based Caching System

Tags: java, caching

Currently we are looking to employ a caching system that reduces load on the database and the server.Our System is not entirely massive,and neither can it be said as small.But currently the load on the database is so huge that a monthly report causes some 3 hours.We started with JCS and had some issues,so investigation on the issues is running as a separate process.In the meanwhile I would like to know about what kind of caching system can I employ.I know some such as Ehcache but JCS outperforms this,then JBoss cache.But many say if you are looking for a caching solution which is new then go for infispan rather than jboss cache.I would like to have some expert opinions on this.But this any downside of using an enterprise level cache in a small application.

Comment: Without knowing specifics of your use case, this is a [shopping recommendation question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). The best way to find out which library is best for you is to try it; a comprehensive expert-level evaluation of major Java cache systems would be a massive answer, and the question is much more likely to attract anecdotal success / horror stories.

Comment: I know my use case.But investigating specifics of each caching system is not a feasible solution for me.Thats why asked this question since there are many experts in this site who have hands-on experience with such API's.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928446/third-party-caching-software-what-do-they-provide

Comment: I know what a cache is,but I want to know which is the best,though this is trivial and based upon my requirements,thats why I want to know whether there is any downside of using enterprise level in a normal not so big application.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer ehcache [url](http://ehcache.org/)

Comment: But isnt JCS faster than ehcache,the benchmark tests on the JCS website say that.

Comment: what are the issues that you mention with JCS?

Comment: Concurrent(simultaneous) access to the cache causes data loss.One thread puts data into the cache using a for loop for 10 iterations and another does the same iterations and reads it back.I have asked this issue in a separate question.I have tried synchronizations on my application,but still some puts are lost.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use distributed caching with ehache you need to get license.If you want open source you can go for memcache,infispan,oscache,jboss server cache.

Infispan is open source and written in javva.It is used as a distributed cache.In addition data can be moved to persistent store in infi span.

Jboss cache is a tree structured,transactional cache.Jboss cache is a clustered cache.

Swarm cache is a simple and distributed cache.Mainly designed for clustered and database driven web applications.